# Sending a selectbox value to fancy box

Tags: jquery, forms, fancybox

http://jsfiddle.net/cR2SB/15/

Please check the link above; the code is there.  All I want to do is to send the value from the selectbox to the fancybox.

Need some help people... stuck on this problem for the last two days, and have tried a variety of stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure what's supposed to happen, but it's not clear from the question or the link.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "send the value.. to the fancybox"?  Do you want to populate an HTML element?  Store it somewhere in a fancybox object?

Comment: What is the full url, that part won't work in fancy box need more than just `main_situation_found.php?incident_maincateid=100`

Comment: apologies...it was meant to be index.php?incident_maincateid=100 main_situation_found.php?incident_maincateid=100... basically i wanted to get the 100 which is from the selectbox to the fancybox where i am calling index.php and then i can see the use the incident_maincateid to pull some data from the database...hope that helps..i have updated the code fiddle...

Comment: in index.php i have <? print_r ($_REQUEST); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Until we get more info for your problem, since you are using jQuery anyway I recommend getting select element values like this :

```
href:'index.php?incident_maincateid=' + $('#mySelectboxsituation_found option:selected').val()
```

.

Its cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: $('#mySelectboxsituation_found option:selected').val() - was missing # ..and now its back to square one...Array ( [incident_maincateid] => )

Comment: in index.php i have <? print_r ($_REQUEST); ?>

Comment: I changed, yeah I forgot the `#` and I also switched it to index.php

Comment: maybe its something that is a defect http://code.google.com/p/fancybox/issues/detail?id=63